# How Many USB Controllers Are in the Late 2014 Mac Mini?

Tags: ipad, usb, mac-mini, data-transfer

I am transferring a lot of data to a large number of iPads from a Mac Mini, over USB. I am finding that the late 2014 Mac Mini is significantly faster at completing the transfer than the Mid 2011 model.

If it's relevant - I'm connecting to iPad 2s.

I think I can rule out any CPU / Ram differences.

Have Apple added more USB controllers to the new Mac minis?
My understanding is that the old models had 2 controllers, is it possible that the 2014 model has 4?

Answer (score 1):

The 2011 Mac Mini only have USB2 ports. 
Since 2012, the Mac Minis have USB3 ports.

That probably the reason.

Also, there is only one physical USB controller the Mac Minis [ref1](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Mac+Mini+Mid+2011+Teardown/6131),[ref2](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Mac+Mini+Late+2012+Teardown/11262), that never changed (note: On the 2014 Mac mini, it's integrated in the processor [ref](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Mac+Mini+Late+2014+Teardown/30410),[ref](http://ark.intel.com/fr/products/75030/Intel-Core-i5-4260U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_70-GHz))

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought that the iPad 2 was USB 2, so I didn't think it would make any difference. I've also tested on a 2012 Macbook Pro (with USB 3) and that seems to be around the same speed as the 2011 Mac Mini

Comment: Then maybe its the fact that the controller is now integrated in the Processor ?

Comment: Interestingly, I am also finding that I can only add 19 iPads at a time over USB. When I plug in any more, they don't appear to connect.
Plugging in more through thunderbolt still seems to work.